# Mockito ExceptionInInitializerError caused by NPE

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, mockito

When I run this test I get ExceptionInitializerError. I think the error lies at line I have with marked with "Error". May be I need to do something to take care of that statement in my test but I just can't figure out what. Any help will be much appreciated.

I am using mockito to test this. I don't have the liberty to change the DAOFactory class. So any changes have to be in MyClass.java or in the test class.

As you can see my test method is empty.

**Test class:**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    @InjectMocks MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    @Mock DAOFactory daoFactory;
    @Mock MyDao dao;

    @Test
    public void myMethodTest(){

    }
}
```

**Class to be tested:**

```
public class MyClass{   
    private MyDao dao = DAOFactory.getInstance().getMyDao();    
    public void myMethod(){
    }
}

public class DAOFactory {
    private static DAOFactory instance = new DAOFactory();
    private DAOFactory() {}

    public static DAOFactory getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    final private CustDao custDao= new CustDao();//-------Error-----------
    final private MyDao dao = new MyDao();//-------Error-----------

    public MyDao getMyDao(){
        return dao;
    }
}
```

**Failute trace:**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:222)
    at com.mycomp.nom.service.impl.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:15)
    at com.mycomp.nom.service.impl.IHardCloseoutTimeServiceImplTest.<init>(IHardCloseoutTimeServiceImplTest.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:516)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:195)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:244)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycomp.core.persistence.hibernate.AbstractDAO.<init>(AbstractDAO.java:71)
    at com.mycomp.bbm.core.persistence.hibernate.AbstractDAO.<init>(AbstractDAO.java:58)
    at com.mycomp.nom.dao.hibernate.AbstractTDAO.<init>(AbstractTDAO.java:52)
    at com.mycomp.nom.dao.hibernate.HibernateAggregateMailClassDAO.<init>(HibernateAggregateMailClassDAO.java:38)
    at com.mycomp.nom.dao.DAOFactory.<init>(DAOFactory.java:51)
    at com.mycomp.nom.dao.DAOFactory.<clinit>(DAOFactory.java:42)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: I think you have a typo, `final private CustDao = new CustDao();` will not compile.  You need a variable name.

Comment: and you should look what causes the NPE in AbstractDAO.java:71.

Comment: @Aurand I have fixed my mistake. It was a typo.

Comment: Before we can solve this for you, we need to see the code in `AbstractDao`.  The stack trace says that this is the class that generated the NPE.

Comment: @DavidWallace I do not have access to the source code of AbstractDao.

Comment: Well, I think you'll need to GET access to the source code of `AbstractDao`, if you want to find out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test this class in isolation you have to remove the automatic instantiation of the Dao dependency here :

```
public class MyClass{   
    private MyDao dao = DAOFactory.getInstance().getMyDao();    
    public void myMethod(){
    }
}
```

You could refactor MyClass code with constructors, one for production one for test purpose :

```
public class MyClass{   
   private MyDao dao;

   public MyClass() {
      dao = DAOFactory.getInstance().getMyDao();
   }

   @VisibleForTesting
   MyClass(Dao dao) {   // package visible for the test only
      this.dao = dao;
   }

   public void myMethod() { }
}
```

There you can avoid the problematic instantiation of the real DAO in your test. Which was the reason why you had a `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it may not be okay to include guava library just so I can test. Although I will try out guava just for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: *guava* is not needed, it's just an annotation for documentation purpose, you can create your own annotation for that matter, simply use a one liner comment, or nothing at all (which won't be really meaningful)